# Flutter Error: The getter 'iterator' was called on null in my list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

i am getting my response but the problem is that when i m hitting my api then first it shows Getter Iterator Was Called On Null then after data loads.

This is my utils class.

```
class BlocApi with ChangeNotifier {
  BlocApi.instance() {
    getAllItems();
  }

  List<Categories> _items;

  List<Categories> get getItems => _items;

  setItems(List<Categories> items) async {
    _items = items;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> getAllItems() async {
    Response response = await get('api Link');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      var rest1 = data['Categories'] as List;

      List<Categories> totalList = new List<Categories>();
      for (var u in rest1) {
        final items1 = Categories.fromJson(u);
        totalList.add(items1);
      }
      setItems(totalList);
    } else {}
  }
}
```

then after this is my First Tab, and i am calling my api to different tabs.

```
class _BevaragesState extends State<Bevarages> {
  List<Itemsss> _items = new List<Itemsss>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); 
  }

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BlocApi blocApi = Provider.of<BlocApi>(context);
    for (var u in blocApi.getItems) {
      if (u.categoryName == 'Bevarages') {
        for (var v in u.items) {
          _items.add(v);
        }
      }
    }

    return Scaffold( 
       body: Container(
         child: ListView.builder(
           itemCount: blocApi.getItems == null ? 0 : _items.length,
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0),
                child: Column(
                   children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                      child: Image.network(
                        'http://dum9b973t0902.cloudfront.net/${_items[index].itemImage}',
                        height: 70.0,
                        width: 70.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Wrap(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  _items[index].itemName,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Arimo',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontSize: 15.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Price : ',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  _items[index].price,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Arimo',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    fontSize: 13.0,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: You can wrap your ListView with FutureBuilder or you can check your response status with a ternary operator. Show CircularProgressIndicator if it is not 200, show list view if it is 200.

Comment: ya i m checking status it's coming 200.  i have some questions about my problem.    1. M using provider so m using context in Build method? if i will not use in build method then my code throws error.

Comment: Yes, you should use context because you are using Provider.

Comment: yes that's the main problem here, i m using my context in build method that's why my list is coming null when the first tab activity loads. so i want to solve this problm. i want to show shimmering effect when list is null means when my activity is in init state

Comment: You can move that item.count logic from build method to your utils class or initState. After that depending on fetching status, you can build shimmer list or actual list.

Comment: we cannot use context in initstate while using provider package

Comment: Then, it is best to move that logic to bloc.

Comment: i have about 2000 items so can i save it in sharedpreference and call all the data according to category in flutter? is it preffered to store 200 items in shared preference?

Comment: yes, no problem but hive can be faster. Check performance comparison: https://github.com/hivedb/hive#benchmark

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to come from `var rest1 = data['Categories'] as List;` since `[]` can't be defined to an `Iterable`. This would cause an issue on your iterator `for (var u in rest1)`. I assume that you're trying to define `data` as a Map, I suggest moving this to your model - inside `Categories.fromJson(Map)`.

I suggest trying this code for mapping the json response to a List.

```dart
var data = json.decode(response.body);

List<Categories> totalList = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data).map((Map model) {
    // Add model mapped from json to List<Categories>
    totalList.add(Categories.fromJson(model));
}).toList();
setItems(totalList);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to check whether item in a list is null or not.

```
if (filterRestaurantList[index].category != null) {
       for (var category
       in filterRestaurantList[index].category) {
       if (category.categoryDetail != null) {                            
         categoryList.add(category.categoryDetail.categoryName);
       }
 }
```